# Achieve 99% accuracy with svm

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I was going through this paper: https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7080/9/3/52, it compares different data scaling methods on different algorithms to see how performance is impacted.
using this database: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/45/heart+disease, splitting it into training and testing, 0.8 and 0.2 respectively and using 10 fold cross validation for evaluation, they achieved 99% accuracy with svm model without scaling and yet i couldn't re-produce those results. any tips?

Comment: Contact the authors and call them on their bulls-chnitzel.

Comment: I've reproduced a number of papers in my life. Usually, discrepancies between published results and reproductions are not due to malpractice, but arise from (1) inconsistent data partitions (2) non-determinism in the software (3) inconsistent computing environments (4) steps which were taken in code but not described in the paper. Of course, there are many more possible reasons!

Comment: I agree with Sycorax's points, but I do want to note that this is from MDPI...they are known as a predatory journal and I have multiple times seen pretty egregious statistical practices in some of their articles. I'm not entirely surprised that you may have found something iffy about their reporting.

Comment: not that it matters alot, the best result I got is 90% accuracy for non scaled data, after exploring many different values for random_state param in sklearn's/ train_test_split() method.